# How to find concentration of three species from given molar absorptivities

Tags: concentration, spectrophotometry

If I am given the molar absorptivities of three species at a given wavelength, and I only have the concentration of one of those species, how can I determine the concentrations of each of the remaining two species? The distance light travels, the molar absorptivities and the amount of light absorbed are given.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE!  Anyone is welcome to contribute answers but the aim of this site is quality and usefulness to future users. Please take a minute to look over the [help center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) and [tour page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand our guidelines and question policies. and please consider providing your thoughts in attempting to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you need would seem to be $\ce{A=\epsilon [C] L}$ where A is the amount of absorption (optical density), L the cell path length, your 'distance light travels' and [C] concentration. As you have 3 species absorbing at the same wavelength you have $\ce{A=(\epsilon_1[C_1] + \epsilon_2[C_2] + \epsilon_3[C_3])L}$. You know L and the $\epsilon$'s but only one of the three concentrations and therefore you do not have enough information to determine the two remaining ones.

Comment: Which, mathematically speaking, is "an underdetermined system" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system).